# ReactJS image not displaying when src is passed in from parent

Tags: reactjs, image

I have a control component:

```
import myImage from 'myImagePath';
...
render() {
  return (
    <ImageComponent source={myImage} />
  );
}
```

And another component, ImageComponent:

```
render() {
  return (
    <img alt="myImage" src={this.props.source} />
  );
}
```

This renders nothing to the page. When I run `console.log(this.props.source)` I see: "static/media/myImage.png". Seems legit.

But if I add an `<img>` tag to the control component itself, I see the image just fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post a link to a running example of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation, this issue occurs only when using 'react-bootstrap' Carousel component. Normal passing of the imported image as a property to another component with straight ReactJS is working as expected.

I suppose Carousel.Item doesn't like being separated from its, "Parent". Defeats the purpose of composition doesn't it?

Comment: I am facing the same problem can you elaborate your solution more into code example please thanks. I am suing Carousel as well

Answer (score 0):

1st thing) Make sure `ImageComponent.js` and its parent container (where you import the image) are in the same folder in your file tree.

```
|imageFolder
| -img.jpg
|javscriptFolder
| -Parent.js
| -ImageComponent.js
```

Lastly) In react, Ive had better luck with `` <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.source})` }} /> ``

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response. Yes, my elements are all within the src tree. Secondly, I can't rely on luck. :(  I prefer API and documentation. But, unfortunately, neither of these comment on this area. At least, that I've seen. As far as your potential fix, This seem unusual to me. Maybe legacy syntax from previous versions of ReactJS? I'd rather find a reasonable solution or reason why I can't pass the imported reference downstream.

Comment: Still, try <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.source})` }} />

Comment: I resist this style as it doesn't follow the normal patterns I see with ReactJS or Bootstrap. But for the sake of curiosity, I tried it. React throws an error of unexpected token on the open { after the $.